# How would I animate the width of a button based on percentage, and the same for it's backgroundColor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-native

I have some `<AnimatedButton />`

I want to animate it to go from 100% width to 40% width depending on a prop that is a boolean called `isFullWidth`.

I have:

```
class AnimatedButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { width: new Animated.Value(100) };
    }
    toggleWidth() {
      const endWidth = this.props.isFullWidth ? 40 : 100;

      Animated.timing(this.state.width, {
        toValue: endWidth,
        duration: 200,
        easing: Easing.linear,
      }).start();
    }

    render() {
      <TouchableOpacity
       style={{ width: `${this.state.width}%` }}
       onPress={this.props.onPress}
      >
       // more stuff
      </TouchableOpacity>
    }
}
```

The problem is that it just jumps into the appropriate percentage without animating. I tried setting the width to just `this.state.animatedValue` and rather than use percentage, just use pixels, e.g. 150 to 400 and back, and it works fine as expected.

Same question applies for going from say `rgba(220, 100, 50, 0.8)` to `rgba(30, 70, 30, 1.0)` and back?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I would suggest you to read more about [interpolation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html#interpolation) because it is very useful when doing almost any kind of animation in React Native.

Basically with `interpolate` you can map some animated values to so other values. In your case you want to map number between 40-100 to a percent string like `50%`. Second thing you want to do is to map number between 40-100 to color from (as an example) red to blue.

Read interpolate docs fully and experiment with it and ask if you have questions after that :)

So I would do it like this:

```
class AnimatedButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { width: new Animated.Value(100) };
  }

  toggleWidth() {
    const endWidth = this.props.isFullWidth ? 40 : 100;

    Animated.timing(this.state.width, {
      toValue: endWidth,
      duration: 200,
      easing: Easing.linear,
    }).start();
  }

  render() {
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{
        width: this.state.width.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: ['0%', '100%'],
        }),
        backgroundColor: this.state.width.interpolate({
          inputRange: [40, 100],
          outputRange: ['rgba(30, 70, 30, 1.0)', 'rgba(220, 100, 50, 0.8)'],
        }),
      }}
      onPress={this.props.onPress}
    >
      // more stuff
    </TouchableOpacity>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the input and output range for the width go up to 100 instead of 1?

Comment: also I think `onPress` should use `toggleWidth` method, not props.onPress. Right?